# WPF - How to update ProgressBar based on the progress of a method from a different class?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5

In my WPF application, I have a ProgressBar for which I would like to dynamically set the `Value` property of, depending on the progress made within a method of another class. However I am unsure on how to do this.

The class and method that's doing the work is along the lines of:

```
public class WorkerClass
{
    public void doSomething(string filePath)
    {
        using (var package = new Package(filePath)) 
        {
            foreach (var item in package) 
            {
                updateMethod(item); //once this method call is complete I want the ProgressBar to update its Value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Within the MainWindow.xaml.cs class, the method of concern is a `button_Click()` method:

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Value = 10;

    WorkerClass worker = new WorkerClass();
    worker.doSomething(txtFilePath.Text); //I want the ProgressBar value to update during this method execution

    progressBar.Value = 100;    
}
```

I tried using the `async/await` keywords, applying it to the `doSomething()` method and returning a `Task<int>` object and the applying `progressBar.Value = await doSomething()` but the ProgressBar still updated synchronously.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a [`Progress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=netframework-4.8) to report progress, and [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Run_System_Action_) to move the processing to a background thread.

If you don't move the processing to a background thread, it will happen on the UI thread. This means that the UI thread is busy doing your processing, and so can't update the progress bar (and your application will appear frozen).

`Progress<T>` lets you define an action which is called every time the progress is reported, using the [`Report`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1.report?view=netframework-4.8#System_IProgress_1_Report__0_) method on the corresponding [`IProgress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1?view=netframework-4.8) interface, which we'll use to update the progress bar. It also makes sure that this action is called on the UI thread<sup>1</sup> regardless of which thread its `Report` method is called on. This means that it's safe to call `Report` from our background thread, and our progress bar will still be updated from the UI thread.

```
public class WorkerClass
{
    public void doSomething(string filePath, IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        using (var package = new Package(filePath)) 
        {
            foreach (var item in package) 
            {
                updateMethod(item); //once this method call is complete I want the ProgressBar to update its Value
                progress.Report(...);
            }
        }
    }
}

private async void btnUpload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Value = 10;

    var progress = new Progress<int>(x => progressBar.Value = x);

    string filePath = txtFilePath.Text;
    WorkerClass worker = new WorkerClass();
    await Task.Run(() => worker.doSomething(filePath, progress));

    progressBar.Value = 100;    
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Strictly it captures the current SynchronizationContext when it's constructed, and uses this when calling the Action passed to its constructor. If it's constructed on the UI thread, this means that the Action is invoked on the UI thread.

Comment: Just about to post the _exact_ answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @canton7, however upon making these changes on my code and running the program, I get the exception thrown at the `await Task.Run(()...` line "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." - would you know why that could be?

Comment: @RoyalSwish Ah, because of the access to `txtFilePath.Text`. See my edit

Comment: Just want to mention that `OnReport` is not part of the `IProgress<T>` API. It's a `protected virtual` method of `Progress<T>`, which is only accessible when deriving from `Progress<T>`. `Progress<T>.Report` internally invokes ``Progress<T>.OnReport` which actually posts the progress delegate to the captured `SynchronizatiopnContext`.

Comment: Never mind. Don't wanted to be rude. Just keep going :)

Comment: @RoyalSwish In case it wasn't clear, you can't access `txtFilePath.Text` from a non-UI thread. So we need to make sure we read it from the UI thread, before we call `Task.Run`