# How to run the UI Grafik and reader function without letting the UI get stopped until function ends?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

My programm is in WPF and i use the MVVM pattern. I also use caliburn micro and material design.

So I have view with a button which loads the path of a csv file. The other Button starts a function that makes things with the csv data.

The calculation and the editing of the csv file takes like 30 sek(csv has 1000 lines and 155 "columns"). I wanted to have a progress bar in my view to show the user that sth is done. But when i press the button I get my progress bar but it stands still until the calculation is done.

How do i prevent that. Maybe use two threads but I didnt get anywhere with that approach is there a nice way to do both things without using two threads?

Maybe sth with task and async but im not sure how to use that in MVVM

My Program loads every line of the csv in an array (time ca. 80ms) The splitting and trimming take like 20 sek

Here is my Splitter maybe i can make that part faster

```
public string Line; //the line of the CSV file
string[] LineContent; //the array where i save the daughter strings

public void Splitter()
{
    LineContent = Line.Split(';');
    for (int i = 0; i < LineContent.Length; i++)
    {
        LineContent[i] = LineContent[i].Trim('"');
    }
}
```

Here is my loading bar

```
<Window.Resources>
   <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
</Window.Resources>

<ProgressBar
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.Row="2"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
    Height="10"
    Visibility="{Binding stopLoadingBar, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
    IsIndeterminate="True">
</ProgressBar>
```

```
public void ReadButPress()
{
   stopLoadingBar = "True";
   CSVReader.Splitter();
   stopLoadingBar = "false";
}
```

So i want to do change the Variable stopLoadingBar to True when i press my button and set it to false when the loading of the function that was called by the button is finished. I tried binding it to two Variables but that did not solve the Problem.

Comment: I reccomend you to learn [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) and then as for ProgressBar, use Progress<T> as shown in  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61101180/3137337

Comment: It took time but i made it work with Async thanks alot