# How to get current progress when printing using PrintDialog?

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, documentviewer

I want to keep showing the currently ongoing Page out of the entire page on the UI thread.

However, no event can be referenced.

I've seen these links:

[WPF - How to update ProgressBar based on the progress of a method from a different class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61101094/wpf-how-to-update-progressbar-based-on-the-progress-of-a-method-from-a-differe)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1165557/wpf-download-file-with-progress-bar

I have the following code now, but I don't know how to do it.

Is there any better way?

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="80" Click="PrintButtonClick">print</Button>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="progressbar" Margin="10,0" Maximum="100" Width="140" Height="20" Value="{Binding Progress}"/>
        <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Width="50" Text="{Binding ProgressValue}"/>
    </StackPanel>
   
    <DocumentViewer Name="viewer"  Grid.Row="1">
        <FixedDocument x:Name="fd">

        </FixedDocument>
    </DocumentViewer>
  
</StackPanel>


using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Xps.Packaging;
using Window = System.Windows.Window;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using PrintDialog = System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog;

namespace DocumentViewerPrintProgressbar
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, ICommand, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        TextBlock page1Text = new TextBlock();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();


            fd.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = new Size(pd.PrintableAreaWidth, pd.PrintableAreaHeight);

            for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                FixedPage page1 = new FixedPage();
                page1.Width = fd.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width;
                page1.Height = fd.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height;

                UIElement page1Text = pages();
                page1.Children.Add(page1Text);
                PageContent page1Content = new PageContent();
                ((IAddChild)page1Content).AddChild(page1);
                fd.Pages.Add(page1Content);
            }
        }
        private UIElement pages()
        {
            Canvas pcan = new Canvas();

            TextBlock page1Text = new TextBlock();
            page1Text.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
            for (int i = 1; i < 1200; i++)
            {
                page1Text.Text += i.ToString() + "This is a testssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss";
            }
            page1Text.FontSize = 40;
            page1Text.Margin = new Thickness(96);

            pcan.Children.Add(page1Text);


            return pcan;
        }



        void PrintButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dlg = new PrintDialog();

            // Allow the user to select a PageRange
            dlg.UserPageRangeEnabled = true;

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                DocumentPaginator paginator =  fd.DocumentPaginator;
                dlg.PrintDocument(paginator, "Just a test");

            }
        }
        public string ProgressValue { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public double Progress { get; set; }
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            Progress = 0;
        }
        
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = "") => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        public static bool PrintWholeDocument(string xpsFilePath, bool hidePrintDialog = false)
        {
            PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
            if (!hidePrintDialog)
            {
                bool? isPrinted = printDialog.ShowDialog();
                if (isPrinted != true)
                    return false;
            }
            try
            {
                XpsDocument xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(xpsFilePath, FileAccess.Read);
                FixedDocumentSequence fixedDocSeq = xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
                DocumentPaginator docPaginator = fixedDocSeq.DocumentPaginator;
                printDialog.PrintDocument(docPaginator, $"Printing {System.IO.Path.GetFileName(xpsFilePath)}");
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

       
    }
}
```

**Update:**

```
   private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Topmost = false;
            PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
            CancellationTokenSource printServerWatchTaskCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            PrintServer printServer = new PrintServer(PrintSystemDesiredAccess.AdministrateServer);
            if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                Task printServerTask = new Task(async () =>
                {
                    await this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(async () =>
                    {
                        PrintQueue _queue = new PrintQueue(printServer, printDialog.PrintQueue.FullName);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        PrintSystemJobInfo job;

                        while (true)
                        {
                            _queue.Refresh();
                            if (_queue.NumberOfJobs > 0)
                            {
                                sb.Clear();
                                job = _queue.GetPrintJobInfoCollection().Where(x => x.Name.Equals("AbleSoft PostDocument2.0")).SingleOrDefault();
                                if (job != null)
                                {
                                    switch (job.JobStatus)
                                    {
                                        case PrintJobStatus.Spooling:
                                            sb.AppendLine($"Spooling");
                                            sb.AppendLine($"{job.NumberOfPages} / {PrintTargetFileInfo.Count}");
                                            break;
                                        case PrintJobStatus.Printing:
                                        case (PrintJobStatus.Printing | PrintJobStatus.Retained):
                                            sb.AppendLine($"Printing");
                                            sb.AppendLine($"{job.NumberOfPagesPrinted} / {PrintTargetFileInfo.Count}");
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    ProgressText.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                                    {
                                        ProgressText.Text = sb.ToString();
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                            await Task.Delay(1);
                        }
                    }, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
                    await Task.Delay(1);
                }, printServerWatchTaskCancellationTokenSource.Token);

                printServerTask.Start();
                printDialog.PrintDocument(documentViewer.Document.DocumentPaginator, "AbleSoft PostDocument2.0");
                printServerWatchTaskCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            }
        }
```

Comment: The way windows printing works is decoupled from the app sending something to print. You might be able to use wmi to find out whether a page has been printed by a printer. I'm not so sure about relating that to a specific print request. Apps do not show you which page is being printed as you describe.  printdialog is probably blocking as well. As in modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The `PrintDialog` is not using any `async` API. So printing is synchronous. This means you can't update the UI in realtime.

As a solution you would have to print the document manually. This allows to use asynchronous APIs. In addition, you get more control over the process (for example you can pick a printer or configure the print job explicitly).
To allow the user to pick a printer, you would have to create your own custom small dialog.
A custom `DocumentPaginator` implementation (`RangeDocumentPaginator`) is used to support printing page ranges.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
private CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource { get; set; }

private async void OnPrintButtonClickedAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
  DocumentPaginator documentPaginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)this.Document).DocumentPaginator;
  var progressReporter = new Progress<(int PageNumber, int Percentage)>(ReportProgress);
  using var printer = new DocumentPrinter();
  this.ProgressBar.Maximum = await printer.GetPageCountAsync(documentPaginator);

  this.CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  try
  {
    // Print complete document
    await printer.PrintFullDocumentAsync(documentPaginator, progressReporter, this.CancellationTokenSource.Token);

    // Print document pages 1 to 10. 
    // The page numbers must be converted to indices 0 to 9.
    // The method takes a 'Range' as argument. 
    // 'Range' is defined as inclusive start index and exclusive end index.
    // Therefore the 'Range' for the pages 1 to 10 is '0..10'.
    await printer.PrintDocumentPageRangeAsync(documentPaginator, 0..10, progressReporter, this.CancellationTokenSource.Token);
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException)
  {
  }
  finally
  {
    this.CancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
    this.CancellationTokenSource = null;
  }
}

private void OnCancelButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
  => this.CancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
    
private void ReportProgress((int PageCount, int Percentage) progress) 
  => this.ProgressBar.Value = progress.PageCount;
```

**DocumentPrinter.cs**

```cs
public class DocumentPrinter : IDisposable
{
  private TaskCompletionSource PrintTaskCompletionSource { get; set; }
  private TaskCompletionSource<int> ComputePagesTaskCompletionSource { get; set; }
  private PrintServer PrintServer { get; }
  private IProgress<(int PageNumber, int Percentage)> CurrentProgressReporter { get; set; }
  private bool IsPrintJobPending { get; set; }
  private CancellationToken CancellationToken { get; set; }

  public DocumentPrinter() => this.PrintServer = new LocalPrintServer();

  public Task<int> GetPageCountAsync(DocumentPaginator documentPaginator)
  {
    this.CancellationToken = CancellationToken.None;
    if (!documentPaginator.IsPageCountValid)
    {
      this.ComputePagesTaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<int>(TaskCreationOptions.None);
      documentPaginator.ComputePageCountCompleted += OnCountingPagesCompleted;
      documentPaginator.ComputePageCountAsync();
      return this.ComputePagesTaskCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    return Task.FromResult(documentPaginator.PageCount);
  }

  public async Task PrintFullDocumentAsync(DocumentPaginator documentPaginator, IProgress<(int PageNumber, int Percentage)> progressReporter, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    => await PrintDocumentPageRangeAsync(documentPaginator, .., progressReporter, cancellationToken);

  public Task PrintDocumentPageRangeAsync(DocumentPaginator documentPaginator, Range pageIndexRange, IProgress<(int PageNumber, int Percentage)> progressReporter, CancellationToken cancellationToke)
  {
    this.CancellationToken = cancellationToken;
    this.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    this.IsPrintJobPending = true;
    this.CurrentProgressReporter = progressReporter;
    this.PrintTaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource(TaskCreationOptions.None);
    var rangeDocumentPaginator = new RangeDocumentPaginator(documentPaginator, pageIndexRange);
    if (!rangeDocumentPaginator.IsPageCountValid)
    {
      this.ComputePagesTaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<int>(TaskCreationOptions.None);
      rangeDocumentPaginator.ComputePageCountCompleted += OnCountingPagesCompleted;
      rangeDocumentPaginator.ComputePageCountAsync();
      return this.PrintTaskCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    StartPrintJob(rangeDocumentPaginator);
    this.IsPrintJobPending = false;
    return this.PrintTaskCompletionSource.Task;
  }

  private void StartPrintJob(DocumentPaginator documentPaginator)
  {
    this.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    /* Select the destination printer */

    // Optionally show a custom printer picker dialog
    PrintQueue destinationPrinter = GetPrintQueueFromUser(printServer);

    // Alternatively use the default printer
    PrintQueue destinationPrinter = printServer.DefaultPrintQueue;

    // Alternatively, pick a particular printer explicitly e.g., native PDF printer
    PrintQueue destinationPrinter = this.PrintServer.GetPrintQueue("Microsoft Print to PDF");

    /* Start the printing */

    // Create a XpsDocumentWriter that writes to the printer queue
    XpsDocumentWriter documentWriter = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(destinationPrinter);
    documentWriter.WritingProgressChanged += OnPrintProgressChanged;
    documentWriter.WritingCompleted += OnPrintingCompleted;
    documentWriter.WriteAsync(documentPaginator);
  }

  private PrintQueue GetPrintQueueFromUser(PrintServer printServer)
  {
    PrintQueueCollection printers = printServer.GetPrintQueues();

    // TODO::Implement MyPrinterPickerDialog (extend Window)
    var myPrinterPickerDialog = new MyPrinterPickerDialog(printers);
    myPrinterPickerDialog.ShowDialog();
    return myPrinterPickerDialog.SelectedPrintQueue;
  }

  private void OnCountingPagesCompleted(object sender,
      System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
    var documentPaginator = sender as DocumentPaginator;
    documentPaginator.ComputePageCountCompleted -= OnCountingPagesCompleted;
    if (this.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
      this.ComputePagesTaskCompletionSource.TrySetCanceled(this.CancellationToken);
      this.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
    else
    {
      _ = this.ComputePagesTaskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(documentPaginator.PageCount);
    }

    if (this.IsPrintJobPending)
    {
      StartPrintJob(documentPaginator);
    }
  }

  private void OnPrintProgressChanged(object sender, WritingProgressChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var documentPrinter = sender as XpsDocumentWriter;
    this.CurrentProgressReporter.Report((e.Number, e.ProgressPercentage));
    if (this.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
      documentPrinter.WritingCancelled += OnPrintingCancelled;
      documentPrinter.CancelAsync();
    }
  }

  private void OnPrintingCancelled(object sender, WritingCancelledEventArgs e)
  {
    var documentPrinter = sender as XpsDocumentWriter;
    documentPrinter.WritingCancelled -= OnPrintingCancelled;
    this.PrintTaskCompletionSource.TrySetCanceled(this.CancellationToken);
    this.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  }

  private void OnPrintingCompleted(object sender, WritingCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
    // TODO::Handle errors by checking event args

    documentWriter.WritingCompleted -= OnPrintingCompleted;
    documentWriter.WritingProgressChanged -= OnPrintProgressChanged;
    _ = this.PrintTaskCompletionSource.TrySetResult();
  }

  private bool disposedValue;
  protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    if (!this.disposedValue)
    {
      if (disposing)
      {
        this.PrintServer.Dispose();
      }

      // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override finalizer
      // TODO: set large fields to null
      this.disposedValue = true;
    }
  }

  // // TODO: override finalizer only if 'Dispose(bool disposing)' has code to free unmanaged resources
  // ~DocumentPrinter()
  // {
  //     // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
  //     Dispose(disposing: false);
  // }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
    Dispose(disposing: true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }
}
```

**RangeDocumentPaginator.cs**

```cs
internal class RangeDocumentPaginator : DocumentPaginator
{
  protected RangeDocumentPaginator() : base() { }

  public RangeDocumentPaginator(DocumentPaginator documentPaginator, Range pageNumberRange)
  {
    this.DocumentPaginator = documentPaginator;
    this.PageIndexRange = pageNumberRange;
    if (!this.DocumentPaginator.IsPageCountValid)
    {
      this.DocumentPaginator.ComputePageCountCompleted += OnPageCountCompleted;
      this.DocumentPaginator.ComputePageCountAsync();
    }
    else
    {
      ThrowIfPageRangeIsInvalid();
    }
  }

  private void ThrowIfPageRangeIsInvalid()
  {
    if (this.PageIndexRange.Start.Value < 0
      || this.PageIndexRange.End.Value > this.DocumentPaginator.PageCount)
    {
      throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
    }
  }

  private void OnPageCountCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    => ThrowIfPageRangeIsInvalid();

  public override DocumentPage GetPage(int pageIndex)
  {
    // XpsDocumentWriter will always start with page index 0.
    // We have to use the start page index as offset
    // to return the correct pages of the range from the underlying document.
    // XpsDocumentWriter will use the PageCount property to know how many pages it can fetch.
    // We have manipulated the PageCount property to return the count of the pages contained within the range.
    int pageOffset = this.PageIndexRange.Start.Value;
    pageIndex += pageOffset;
    return pageIndex < this.PageIndexRange.Start.Value
      || (pageIndex >= this.PageIndexRange.End.Value && !this.IsRangeFullDocument)
        ? DocumentPage.Missing
        : this.DocumentPaginator.GetPage(pageIndex);
  }

  public override bool IsPageCountValid => this.DocumentPaginator.IsPageCountValid;

  public override int PageCount
  {
    get
    {
      int range = this.PageIndexRange.End.Value - this.PageIndexRange.Start.Value;
      return this.IsRangeFullDocument
        ? this.DocumentPaginator.PageCount
        : range;
    }
  }

  public override Size PageSize { get => this.DocumentPaginator.PageSize; set => this.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = value; }
  public override IDocumentPaginatorSource Source => this.DocumentPaginator.Source;
  public Range PageIndexRange { get; set; }
  public bool IsRangeFullDocument => this.PageIndexRange.Equals(Range.All);
  private DocumentPaginator DocumentPaginator { get; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Applying this code generates a lot of errors. It seems that these reasons need to be addressed one by one.
Before we look at the answer. `The code update in question worked.`
If you put the corresponding code in a separate program and run it, it works fine.
But if I apply this code to my main project
The task operation and PrintDocument() are not executed at the same time, so the result cannot be printed correctly.

Comment: Hi,@BionicCode . Based on the prompts in the code
`btn_Print_Click`
`private async Task OnPrintButtonClickedAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)` 
I want to replace it with this. Is this a good choice?

Comment: Yes you can rename the event handler (if this was the question?). Just note that the event handler must return void instead of Task. I have fixed it in the example. *"But if I apply this code to my main project The task operation and PrintDocument() are not executed at the same time, so the result cannot be printed correctly."* - Do you still need help with this issue? If so, would you like to explain how you call the code (DocumentPrinter  API)?

Comment: *"Applying this code generates a lot of errors."* - Except for the wrong (now fixed) event handler signature the code should compile and work. It uses the using declaration and the range syntax with the Range type (no supported in .NET Framework) that requires C# 8. But it's very easy to "downgrade" the code to make it compliant with lower language and framework versions.